# VB.NET Save data from textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble with saving text from a TextBox to a file.

Code>

```
If Not File.Exists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\httpd\conf\httpd.conf") Then
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\httpd\conf\httpd.conf", False)
        sw.Write(httpdconf.Text & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\httpd" & httpdconf2.Text & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\www" & httpdconf3.Text & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\www" & httpdconf4.Text & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\cgi-bin" + httpdconf5.Text & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\cgi-bin" & httpdconf6.Text)
    End Using

End If
```

The problem is that the text is saved without the httpdconf.Text lines the program thinks the text is empty (even when not). Even the designer looks strangely

Example>

```
        '
        'httpdconf
        '
        Me.httpdconf.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 68)
        Me.httpdconf.Name = "httpdconf"
        Me.httpdconf.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(77, 102)
        Me.httpdconf.TabIndex = 15
        Me.httpdconf.Text = resources.GetString("httpdconf.Text")
```

Instead of text -->resources.GetString("httpdconf.Text") <--

I don't understand with what the text takes.
(The Text is pre-designated) - (the Text doesn't say user)

Comment: Looks like you edited the designer file yourself.  It includes the warning not to do so.  If the text is static, why cant your add it in form load?  Why put it in a text box where the user can change it if you want that text written out?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

FIXED
I put code that I want to save to a file and the program will be taken from that file. The reason>Congestion of the program when you load a large text after the launch

Code>

```
            Dim apache_1
            Dim apache_2
            Dim apache_3
            Dim apache_4
            Dim apache_5
            Dim apache_6
            Using sr1 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\default_conf\apache_1")
                apache_1 = sr1.ReadToEnd
            End Using
            Using sr2 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\default_conf\apache_2")
                apache_2 = sr2.ReadToEnd
            End Using
            Using sr3 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\default_conf\apache_3")
                apache_3 = sr3.ReadToEnd
            End Using
            Using sr4 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\default_conf\apache_4")
                apache_4 = sr4.ReadToEnd
            End Using
            Using sr5 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\default_conf\apache_5")
                apache_5 = sr5.ReadToEnd
            End Using
            Using sr6 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\default_conf\apache_6")
                apache_6 = sr6.ReadToEnd
            End Using



            Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() + "\httpd\conf\httpd.conf", False)
                sw.Write(apache_1 & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\httpd" & apache_2 & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\www" & apache_3 & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\www" & apache_4 & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\cgi-bin" + apache_5 & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\cgi-bin" & apache_6)
            End Using
```